# Duda con Excel y servlets java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Estoy intentando crear un excel a partir de mi metodo listar que recupera los registros que existen en un base de datos, para eso estoy utilizando Apache POI mi problema es que es una app web y quiero que el cliente pueda descargar un excel entonces lo estoy realizando desde un Servlet ahora mi duda es

¿como puedo mandar el archivo excel creado con apache poi para que el cliente descargue ese archivo?

ya que si utilizo los metodos

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Xxxx.xls")
```

crea un nuevo archivo y no el que ya se creo con apache poi, porfavor ayuda! muchas gracias"

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Comment: ¿ya intentaste además de eso que tu método regrese un arreglo de bytes como es común ahora o escribir el arreglo de bytes en tu objeto Response como se hacía en la vieja escuela?

Comment: Hola amigo, defini un metodo aparte en un paquete y un clase diferente sera eso tambien un problema? cree un paquete de utilidades con la clase CrearExcel y ahi hice todos los pasos para crear el excel, en el servlet solamente estoy mandando a llamar el metodo crearExcel(Le paso una lista) que ya defini antes "List lista = new DAO().listar()" y luego quiero que se descargue ese excel entonces donde tienen que regresar los bytes? en el metodo crearExcel?